# File upload using PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, asyncfileupload

I am able to upload small files without any issues. When I try with a 150mb file, it stops unexpectedly. The following is my HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="form_upload">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label muted">IMG</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="file" id="img" name="img" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label muted">MD5</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="file" id="md5" name="md5" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="percent"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following is my Ajax handler: I am using the jQuery form submit plugin.

```
uploadFirmware:function(){
  var bar = $('.bar');
  var percent = $('.percent');
  self = this;
  var options = {
    beforeSend: function() {
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal)
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal)
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      self.showStatusMsg(1,"<b>Firmware Upload: </b> File Upload successfully");
    },
    url: '/cav_firmware/api',
    iframe: false
  };
  $("#form_upload").ajaxSubmit(options);
  return false;
}
```

And finally this is my PHP code. I am using CodeIgniter, but I am not using that in my code, just a classic PHP script.

```
public function api_post(){
  $filea = $_FILES['img'];
  $fileb = $_FILES['md5'];
  if( move_uploaded_file($filea['tmp_name'], '/home/sreeni/upload/'.$filea['name']) && move_uploaded_file($fileb['tmp_name'], '/home/sreeni/upload/'.$fileb['name'])){
    echo "Success fully upload files";
  } else {
    echo "File upload failed.";
  }
}
```

All this is fine. My issue is only with uploading a 150 MB file. I am getting the following error when I try to upload my MD5 and IMG files:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
  <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
  <p>Severity: Notice</p>
  <p>Message:  Undefined index: img</p>
  <p>Filename: controllers/cav_firmware.php</p>
  <p>Line Number: 30</p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
  <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
  <p>Severity: Notice</p>
  <p>Message:  Undefined index: md5</p>
  <p>Filename: controllers/cav_firmware.php</p>
  <p>Line Number: 31</p>
</div>File upload failed.
```

I changed my `php.ini` to the maximum size 200 MB (memory limit) in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to specify my files are MD5 and IMG (firmware image files)? Any help?

Comment: You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 200M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 200M

Comment: Good. But :( its already done. any other idea ?

Comment: @SRquery, please read question...he already did it

Comment: @Confusion_buddy, did you make sure to restart apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: Did you try uploading the same 150mb file without using AJAX?

Comment: yes i restarted apache :) /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: what is the code in  line 30 and 31?

Comment: Without  using Ajax? bt...in my js app backbone i dont think it is poosible to upload directly with out ajax :(

Comment: $filea = $_FILES['img']; // line 30
$fileb = $_FILES['md5']; // line 31\

Comment: your ajax request isn't timing out, is it? what does the network panel tell you when this fails? what kind of HTTP error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for your maximum execution time of script in php.ini
default time is 30seconds.

Comment: max_execution_time = 30000 ; max_input_time = 60000; memory_limit = 200M; post_max_size = 200M;

Comment: make execution_time bigger like 300000 for bigger upload